# Async calls to WCF services using Castle WCF Facility - issue with thread principal "inheritance"

Tags: c#, wcf, castle, wcffacility

I'm using [Castle WCF Facility](http://kozmic.net/2009/08/09/making-asynchronous-wcf-calls-without-svcutil/) to perform async calls to WCF services, e.g.

```
public void Start()
{
    // original thread

    svc.BeginWcfCall(x => x.GetData(), OnAsyncResult, null);
}

public void OnAsyncResult(IWcfAsyncCall<object[]> asyncCall)
{
    // callback thread
}
```

Is there any built-in way to force `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` being set to the same value as in the caller thread?